# How can I keep my command blocks running even if the closest player is thousands of blocks away?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a PvP world where duplicating is not allowed, so I need to delete piston items from people's inventory. The only problem is, the command blocks only work up to about 200 - 250 blocks away from any players.

Is there any way to make the commands run across the whole entire world at once? For reference I am on *Minecraft Bedrock Edition*.

Comment: That's just chunks unloading. Here is probably your solution: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ticking_area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
/tickingarea add circle (radius) (name)
```

so the game runs everything in the radius of chunks specified in the command, including command blocks.

Answer (score 1):

> It's due to unloading chunks

If you want to use commandblocks all over the map, you need to place them in the spawn chunk.

The spawnchunk is the area you spawn in (when not using a bed). This chunk is always loaded, so commandblocks will work even if there is no player near it

Comment: Spawn chunks only work on the Java edition. As previously stated I am on the Bedrock edition. I also already fixed this but I don't know how to show that.